# fastened to the top of the trousers at the front and back

Tags: grammar

**braces**​
(British English)
(North American English suspenders)
[plural] long narrow pieces of cloth, leather, etc. for holding trousers up. They are **fastened** to **the top of the trousers** **at the front and back** and passed over the shoulders.

[Source](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/brace_1?q=Brace)

---

Does "**at the front and back**" modify "**fastened**" or "**the top of the trousers**"?

Comment: I would say it modifies the whole phrase - _fastened to the top of the trousers_.

Comment: @KateBunting Does "at the front and back" adjectivally modify "the top of the trousers"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It indicates where the fastening is.  The location, and hence manner, of joining the strips of cloth to the trousers.  As such it is adverbial.

It doesn't describe the trousers, or the top of the trousers.